# how to read a property using variables

Tags: shell

Iam facing this problem for past 2/3 days. I have a simple script in which i will read a property file and output some of the contents. This is my script

```
vi testloop.properties
dump_1=abc


vi testloop.sh
. testloop.properties
i=1
dmp="dump_"$i  //as per my understanding dmp=dump_1
echo $dump_1   //abc will echod since dump_1 in property file is abc
echo $dmp      ***i thought here also abc will come but unfortunately it is "dump_1"***
echo $(($dmp)) ***here output is 0*** 


sh testloop.sh
abc
dump_1
0
```

Can some one help me in pointing out what has happend in echo $dmp and echo $(($dmp)) . why it is not echoing abc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dmp="dump_"$i`

This assigns the string `"dump_1"` rather than the variable `dump_1` to `dmp`.

The other example you gave tries to do arithmetic expansion of `$dmp` which in this case is just 0.

Normally the variable assignment would be `dmp=$dump_1`, which is fine, but variable variable assignment, i.e. `dmp=$dump_$i` doesn't work as you might hope.  You can pass it through an `eval` statement like so:

`eval dmp=\$dump_$1`

But if you really need variable variables of this nature it might be better to use an array:

```
i=1
dump[1]='abc'
dmp=${dump[$i]}
echo ${dump[$i]}
echo $dmp
```

Answer (score 2):

```
. ./testloop.properties
i=1
dmp="dump_"$i
echo $dump_1   # print abc as expected
echo $dmp      # prints dump_1 since this is what dmp contains
 # ***here output is 0*** 
eval echo \$$dmp # evaluates \$$dmp to $dump1 then echoes abc
```

As for `echo $(($dmp))`, it tries to evaluate an [arithmetic expression](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC33) and the result is 0:

> Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression
>   and the substitution of the result. The format for arithmetic
>   expansion is:
>
> $(( expression ))

Answer (score 2):

If your shell is bash, use indirect parameter expansion.

```
echo ${!dmp}
```

Documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), a level of variable indirection is introduced. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself. This is known as indirect expansion.

However, using arrays as shown by @FoolishSeth is generally tidier than constructing dynamic variable names.